# How to display rows based on the filtered content of a column?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a table that has three columns:

```
| name | company | country |
```

so I have many people belonging to the same country, I wanted to make another table that made a list of unique companies, and another column that listed how many people belonged to that company like so:

```
| company | num users in company |
```

that was done using [this](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/docs/pD5Zic6n2xU/rGY-GbeI4_YJ) formula

```
B1: Unique names
B2: =SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER( A2:A ; ISTEXT( A2:A))))

C1: # of times occurring
C2: =COUNTIF( A2:A ;SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER( A2:A ; ISTEXT( A2:A))) ))
```

How do I list the countries besides each company mentioned in a separate column, so the end result will look like this?

```
| company | num users in company | country |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you data is in Columns A:C. In several steps because easier (my excuse is that you have not clarified whether a `company` may be associated with more than one `country`):

In E1: `=UNIQUE(QUERY(A:C,"select B,C where B is not NULL order by B,C",1))`

to obtain an ordered list of unique `company` / `country` combinations.

In G1: `Count`, in G2 and copied down to suit: `=countifs(B:B,E2,C:C,F2)`

for the counting of names.

In I1: `=query(E:G,"select E,G,F")`

to rearrange the column order.